# IE8 Error: https error 12007.xml; how to correct?

Tags: security, troubleshooting, internet-explorer-8

I run Windows XP Pro with IE8. If fails to connect to HTTPS sites with the above error.

Any suggestions on how this can be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried enabling compatibility mode for the websites you're having trouble with? It is the "torn in half" page button to the right of the address bar.

Answer (score 0):

Initial googling shows this error occurring  with a several fix suggestions. It seems, there are two main fix suggestions.

1. [Reset IE8 settings](http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2006/06/12/628499.aspx). As suggested [here](http://www.techsupportforum.com/microsoft-support/internet-explorer-forum/256566-ie-7-suddenly-gives-error-12007-a.html)
2. [Reset TCP/IP stack & Winsock entries to default](http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=4625) by typing the following to commands in cmdprompt. As suggested [here](http://forums.techguy.org/networking/786320-dns-issues.html) and [here](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1311127&page=6)

> TCP/IP: **netsh int ip reset reset.log**
>
> WINSOCK: **netsh winsock reset catalog**